# Proving that if $D$ is compact then $D$ is closed, with non obvious hint.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

This is a question from the book: A Course in Multivariable Calculus and Analysis which I am self-studying. Also, it is my first question here and english is not my native language.

I must prove: If $D$ is compact, then $D$ is closed. (Hint: If $(x_0, y_0) \in D\backslash \partial D$, then the set of open squares centered at $(x, y)$ and of radius $|(x, y)−(x_0, y_0)|/2$, as $(x, y)$ varies over $D$, is an open cover of $D$.)

First of all I don't really know how this hint can help me.
I can't see how the set of squares can contain the point $(x_0,y_0)$, because if $(x,y) = (x_0,y_0)$ then the radius is $0$, therefore the square centered at  $(x_0,y_0)$ is the empty set. 
So I can't accept that it is an open cover of $D$.

Supposing it is an open cover of $D$, it must have a finite subcover by compactness of $D$. Which is impossible, because there's always a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ that isn't covered.

And finaly, what could I do with those $(x_0,y_0) \in D\backslash \partial D$?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\partial D\setminus D?$

Comment: If it is, as @zhw suspects $\partial D\setminus D$, then the fact that you cannot find a finite subcover yields a contradiction, so there are no points in $\partial D\setminus D$, hence $D$ is closed.

Comment: It must be a typo from the book?

Comment: Probably it is.

Comment: Here is another way: Suppose $x \notin D$, then consider $m=\min_{d \in D} \|x-d\| $ (existence because of compactness). We must have $m >0$ (otherwise $x \in D$ by compactness), and so $B(x,{1 \over 2}m) $ does not intersect $D$. Hence $D$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks, nice and short explanations are always welcome.

Comment: A compact subset of a Hausdorff space is always closed, and $ \mathbb{R} $ is Hausdorff.

Comment: This  is not true for $all$ topological spaces. But if this is in some $\Bbb R^n$ then it is true.